# How to model the difference in proportion of specific repeat families between two groups

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I want to ask if the proportion of different repeat families in a genome (LINES, SINES, LTR, Other, DNA) differ in guenons compared to outgroups.

The data I have is the following (in a simplified format)
|species|repeat.family|fraction|species_type|
|-------|-------------|--------|------------|
|A_lhoesti|DNA|0.0334|guenons|
|A_lhoesti|LINE|0.187|guenons|
|A_lhoesti|LTR|0.0908|guenons|
|r_roxellana|DNA|0.329|outgroup|
|r_roxellana|LINE|0.205|outgroup|

With 13 species groups (2 outgroups, 11 guenons),
5 repeat.family categories,
and 2 species types.

As my response variable is a fraction, I decided to fit a generalised linear model with a beta regression.

```
model<-betareg(fraction ~ species_type + repeat.family + species_type*repeat.family
```

This was my output:

```
Call:
betareg(formula = fraction ~ species_type + repeat.family + species_type * 
    repeat.family, data = data2, family = binomial)

Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8986 -0.2285  0.0443  0.2611  3.0030 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
                                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                             -3.31171    0.05226 -63.367  < 2e-16 ***
species_typeoutgroup                    -0.06573    0.13655  -0.481  0.63028    
repeat.familyLINE                        1.85460    0.05780  32.088  < 2e-16 ***
repeat.familyLTR                         0.99006    0.06225  15.906  < 2e-16 ***
repeat.familyOther                       0.22832    0.07029   3.248  0.00116 ** 
repeat.familySINE                        1.35377    0.05992  22.592  < 2e-16 ***
species_typeoutgroup:repeat.familyLINE   0.07735    0.15030   0.515  0.60684    
species_typeoutgroup:repeat.familyLTR    0.03029    0.16213   0.187  0.85177    
species_typeoutgroup:repeat.familyOther  0.01038    0.18348   0.057  0.95488    
species_typeoutgroup:repeat.familySINE   0.08337    0.15552   0.536  0.59191    

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(phi)    969.1      170.1   5.698 1.21e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 217.2 on 11 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.9558
Number of iterations: 82 (BFGS) + 3 (Fisher scoring)
```

I dont think this is the way to model this data however.

I am not sure which part of the output gives me the difference between the proportion of each repeat family in guenons and the outgroup.

Is this the interaction term? does this show how the proportion of repeat classes change with the two groups?